# Using Azure EventHub behind a proxy with authentication

Tags: java, azure, proxy, azure-eventhub

**UPDATE**

There are some News on that, see here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/eventhubs/2018/09/21/azure-event-hubs-websockets-and-proxy-support/

**====**

Azure's `EventProcessorHost` can be used to register and `EventProcessor` against an EventHub:

```
EventProcessorHost host = new EventProcessorHost(
    EventProcessorHost.createHostName(null), 
    connectionStringBuilder.getEventHubName(),
    "$Default",
    ConnectionStringBuilder.toString(),
    this.storageConnectionString,
    this.storageContainerName
  );

  host.registerEventProcessor(MyEventProcessor.class, options).get();
```

One can add a proxy beforehand:

```
 OperationContext.setDefaultProxy(
    new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("proxy.url.com", 1234))
 );
```

**Question**: How to provide an authentication (username/password) to this proxy?

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR**: `EventProcessorHost` java library doesn't support proxy yet. This is a feature under construction.

Event Hubs Java Client sdk currently uses AMQPs protocol over TCP (on socket 5671, standard port assigned by IANA) to communicate to Event Hubs Service. We just built, support for `Websockets` transport; here' the [PR](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-java/pull/362). Building a snapshot version on `dev` branch and adding parameter `TransportType=AmqpWebSockets` in the ConnectionString should enable the client to talk to the `EventHubs` service over port 443.

We are building support for proxy using basic auth - by end of September. follow [this for updates](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-java/issues/264).